# How to persist a query between flask page requests?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to run the same exact query on multiple page requests.
The first page renders the items, the second page exports the items to excel.

Storing the query directly on session fails because `BaseQuery` is not JSON serializable:

```
session['previous_query'] = SomeModel.query
```

The next option is to store the query as a string:

```
session['previous_query'] = str(SomeModel.query)
```

This works but I would now need to run session.execute:

```
db.session.execute(session['previous_query'])
```

And that does not give me ORM objects but plain dicts without relationships.

Finally I can store only the ids, but that would require me to run the query on both ends multiple times and would not preserve the ordering I need.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, there are many parameters and filters which would make storing the criteria complicated and bug-prone.

Answer (score 4):

You can serialize the query with the SQLAlchemy Serializer extention:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext import serializer

session['previous_query'] = serializer.dumps(SomeModel.query, -1)
```

then reconstitute the query with:

```
query = serializer.loads(session['previous_query'], db.metadata, db.session)
objects = query.all()
```

where `db` is your Flask-SQLAlchemy integration object.

Under the hood this uses the `pickle` module but pickling has been customized to be more compact and to omit the session and engine references; these are loaded again when loading the serialized data with `serializer.loads()`.

For this to work on Python 2 you do need to set the protocol version (second argument to `serializer.dumps()`) as the seralization won't work with the default protocol version 0. Pick version 1 or 2 instead, or use `-1` to pick the highest version supported by your Python installation.

Because this uses pickle, do be careful with loading the pickle from untrusted sources; a Flask session is tamper proof because it is cryptographically signed, but if an attacker ever was able to obtain your server-side secret then the attacker can take over your process by sending you a carefully crafted pickle for `serializer.loads()` to load.

Comment: @Ramin: this pickles *just* the query, not the instances that query produces. You still need to rerun that query after recreating it.

Comment: I am getting a PicklingError: `File "/home/ramin/projects/tracking/tracking/__init__.py", line 91, in render_residents_index_page
    session['previous_residents_query'] = serializer.dumps(residents)
  File "/home/ramin/projects/tracking/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/serializer.py", line 149, in dumps
    pickler.dump(obj)
PicklingError: persistent id must be string`

Comment: residents is a BaseQuery

Comment: Could flask sqlalchemy be ruining the query?

Comment: @Ramin: trying to reproduce your issue, just a moment.

Comment: I tried doing db.session.query(MyModel) instead of MyModel.query; same issue.

Comment: @Ramin: This appears to be a bug with the SQLAlchemy serializer, actually; it returns a unicode value at some point, instead of a string.

Comment: @Ramin: I believe that [this commit](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/commits/2aa00c49d7a1a783ff50832f2de77) broke this functionality, I'll follow up with the maintainer.

Comment: @Ramin: ah, this only applies to protocol version 0; use `-1` to use the latest protocol version and it works.

Comment: yup. What' does setting protocol to -1 actually do?

Comment: @Ramin: instruct `pickle` to use the latest version.